# SASS + CSS Injecting with Gulp and BrowserSync

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, browser-sync

Just getting started with BrowserSync and I have a question regarding the common use-cases on configuration for SASS + CSS injecting.

What I'm a little confused about is weather I can give the `server` property its own name.

In the docs [here](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/) they use `"./app"`. Can I use another name like `"./site"` or am I only allowed to use `"./app"`?

Here's the code

```
// task 
gulp.task('serve',['sass'], function (){

    // static server 
    browserSync.init({
        server: "./app"
    });

    // watching html and scss files for changes then reloading browser
    gulp.watch("app/scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

If you're looking to set up `browserSync` as a static server with live reloading you're pretty much right with your approach. You can point browsersync to any folder in your repository using the `baseDir` option. You can also use multiple directories. For further info check out the options [documentation](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-server).

First. I would look to split up the tasks you have.

Personally, I would opt to have my server task something like;

```
gulp.task('serve', ['build'], function(event) {
  var server = browsersync.create();
  server.init({
    baseDir: 'app/'
  });
  return server.watch('app/**', function(evt, file) {
    server.reload();
  });
});
```

Note how `build` is a dependency. This ensures that all of our served files are in place when we initiate BrowserSync.

Keeping it generic we can then split the SCSS related tasks into their own tasks such as `scss:compile` and `scss:watch`.

```
gulp.task('scss:compile', function(){
    return gulp.src('src/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(scss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css/');
});
```

and

```
gulp.task('scss:watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', ['scss:compile']);
});
```

For CSS injection. There are two options for doing this

Remember injection differs from reload. Whereas reload will reset the page state, injection won't affect the current page state and justs injects the styles.

Option one is to invoke `browsersync.stream()` with the piped content of your SASS compilation like follows;

```
gulp.task('scss:compile', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(scss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')
    .pipe(browsersync.stream());
});
```

Note that the last pipe injects the changes. This also requires to check the file type in the BrowserSync watch to only reload when a non CSS file changes.

This option is OK. However, I think it's not clear to have it just bundled on the end there and separate from BrowserSync setup code.

The second option(*personally preferred*) is to watch for changes with BrowserSync and if a CSS file changes, use `vinyl` to stream those changes to BrowserSync.

Something like the following tends to work;

```
var gulp      = require('gulp'),
  browsersync = require('browser-sync'),
  vss         = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
  vb          = require('vinyl-buffer'),
  vf          = require('vinyl-file');

gulp.task('serve', ['build'], function() {
  var server = browsersync.create();
  server.init({ baseDir: 'app/' });
  return server.watch('app/**', function(evt, file) {
    if (evt === 'change' && file.indexOf('.css') === -1)
      server.reload();
    if (evt === 'change' && file.indexOf('.css') !== -1)
      vf.readSync(file)
        .pipe(vss(file))
        .pipe(vb())
        .pipe(server.stream());
  });
});
```

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help here @jh3y I see how your setting things up and I will follow your generic approach to this.

Comment: can you please explain this line `return gulp.watch('app/**/*.*).on('change', browserSync.reload); ` I cant seem to make sense of how this line is going to work with my current gulp file set up.

Comment: I'm new to **Gulp**  also :)

Comment: That line `return gulp.watch('app/**/*.*).on ...` watches for any files within your output folder changing and upon change reloads the server.

If we are to assume you only have `css`, `js`, and `html` in your output folder you could change the glob to something like `app/**/*.{html,css,js}`.

Comment: Thanx! Got Browsersync to work but I'm unable to see my changes auto reload in the browser (live updating) check out the post I just made.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279766/browsersnyc-not-auto-reloading-on-changes-made-to-css

Comment: Hey Brent, no problem I'll take a look.