# Browsersnyc not auto reloading on changes made to css

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser-sync

Got Browsersync to work with my Gulp file but I've really been struggling with getting browsersync to auto reload my static site when I make changes to the `main.scss` file. I've followed all the documentation on there webpage thoroughly and I still cant get page to auto refresh.

I know parts of my integration with gulp are working because when I run my default gulp task which is linked to the `browser-sync` task a browser window fires up with the server but when I make s simple change to my `main.scss` file nothing auto reloads. I have to manually refresh to see changes.

Here's my gulpfile..What am I missing in here?

```
// refferance gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// browser-sync
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
// other packages installed
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var scss = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

// browser-sync task
gulp.task('browser-sync',['styles'] , function(){
    browserSync.init({
        server:'./'
    });
    gulp.watch('.//src/scss/*.scss',['styles']);
    gulp.watch('.//*.html').on('change',browserSync.reload);
});

// scripts task
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    // fetch all files in the .js extension in the /src/js directory
    return gulp.src('./src/js/*.js')
    // concatenate files and save as app.js
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    // save app.js in dest directory
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest/js/'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    // minfiy file and rename to app.min.js
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    // save in dest directory
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest/js'));
});


// styles task
gulp.task('styles', function(){
     // fetch all files with scss extension in /src/scss directory
    return gulp.src('./src/scss/*.scss')
    // compile scss
    .pipe(scss())
    // output css in css dest directory
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest/css/'))
    // minify css
    .pipe(cssmin())
    // rename as styles.min.css
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    // save in same directory
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest/css'))
    // reload browser by injecting css into browser via browsersync
    // .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.watch('./src/js/*.js', ['scripts']);


// we use the watch task in the default task bellow
gulp.task('watch',function(){
    // watch js
    gulp.watch('./src/js/*.js',['scripts']);
    // watch scss
    gulp.watch('./src/scss/*.scss',['styles']);
});

// default task allows us to run all tasks at once by just running `gulp` in command line

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'styles', 'browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take out

```
gulp.watch('.//src/scss/*.scss',['styles']);
gulp.watch('.//*.html').on('change',browserSync.reload);
```

and replace with

```
gulp.watch('dest/**/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

you should see changes providing that you are looking at a HTML file located under the `dest` directory.

I would also check that your `styles` and `scripts` tasks are firing. You should see this in the terminal/cli. If they are firing, any reload will also be logged too.

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: All my styles and scripts are firing perfectly. Compiling scss into css and minifying.  Still no result when I change the color of an `h1` via my `main.scss` `index.html` is located in the root directory so I used this line `gulp.watch('./.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);`

Comment: No result as in I do not see the page reload. I haft to manually reload to see result

Comment: I'll send you the link to my repo

Comment: Ahh OK but if you changed `main.scss` this would update your CSS file wherever that is located and wouldn't trigger the change as the HTML file has not been changed.

Comment: so thats why I had this line `gulp.watch('.//src/scss/*.scss',['styles']);` but still that did nothing! ha

Comment: That `scss` watch would be redundant however I believe as its a duplicate of what is contained within your general watch task?

Comment: true. I put it in the `browserSync` task thinking that was how I got browerSync to see the changes..

Comment: https://github.com/kapena/portfolio_ check out my repo and see if you can see where I'm going wrong